# What is solution for constructor in functional components in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Let me take you to my problem. I am making a timer functional component, I am passing startValue to component and then that component will start timer(decreasing one in second) using  startValue passed through props.

```
const FunctionalComponent = (props: any) => {

const [timerValue, setTimerValue] = useState(props.initialValue)

console.log('Set State')

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('UseEffects called')

    setInterval(() => {
        setTimerValue(timerValue - 1)
    }, 1000)

}, [])

return <View><Text style={styles.textStyle}>{timerValue}</Text></View>
```

}

My render function in Parent.

```
render() {
    return <View style={styles.mainView}>
        <FunctionalComponent  initialValue={30} />
    </View>
}
```

Now, Every time react re-render parent component, FunctionalComponent gets called and resets timerValue value. I solved this problem using class component constructor, but I wonder is there any solution to do same in functional components.

```
class OTPTimer extends Component {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            timeLeft: props.fromStart
        }

        if (props.startTimer) {

            this.startTimer()

        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps: any) {

        if (!prevProps.startTimer && this.props.startTimer) {
            this.startTimer()
            this.setState({
                timeLeft: this.props.fromStart
            })
        }
    }

    startTimer = () => {
        var interval = setInterval(() => {

            this.setState({
                timeLeft: this.state.timeLeft - 1
            })

            if (this.state.timeLeft === 0) {
                clearInterval(interval)

            }

        }, 1000)
    }

    render() {
        return <Text style={globalStyles.testStyleThree}>{`00:${this.state.timeLeft > 9 ? this.state.timeLeft : `0${this.state.timeLeft}`}`}</Text>
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where it makes sense to use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) in order to prevent re-rendering child components when their props don't change.

> React.memo is a higher order component. It’s similar to
> React.PureComponent but for function components instead of classes.
>
> If your function component renders the same result given the same
> props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost
> in some cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip
> rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.

```
    const FunctionalComponent = React.memo<{initialValue: number}>({initialValue}) => {
      const [timerValue, setTimerValue] = useState(initialValue)
    
      console.log('Set State')
    
      useEffect(() => {
          console.log('UseEffects called')
    
          setInterval(() => {
              setTimerValue(timerValue - 1)
          }, 1000)
    
      }, [])
    
      return <View><Text style={styles.textStyle}>{timerValue} 
 </Text></View>

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

checkout [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), witch will prevent child component to re-render if it's props has not changed

```
const FunctionalComponent = React.memo((props: any) => { .... } )
```

Answer (score 0):

People suggested `useEffect` but it will be invoked after render.

Use `useMemo` instead:

```
useMemo(() => {
  console.log('This is useMemo')
}, []);
```